# How to convert java AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding to php

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I'm trying to convert a java script to php, but i'm having a hard time, can someone help me

```
String key = "mykey123823196ext470329981320tst";
String str = "Emma";
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
byte[] IV = new byte[16];
    
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
        
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        
String result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        
System.out.println(result); // OUTPUT: wuN9UzYYdmevVxgTxcYIbw==
```

This is what i tried but the result is not the same as the output of java code

```
$str = 'Emma';
$key = 'mykey123823196ext470329981320tst';
$iv  = '0000000000000000';
$encodedEncryptedData = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($str, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
echo $encodedEncryptedData; // OUTPUT: Vn5U9IbbxtQWxyeiLKBu9A==
```

Comment: Your IV on Java is 16 HEX '0x00's (16 bytes filled with 0) but your PHP-IV is 16 times ASCII '0'). Just a note on your encryption scheme: the usage of a static IV makres your complete encryption **unsecure** - for other readers: **Do not use the code above in production**. Please use a random generated IV, prepend it to the ciphertext so that the receipient can split the data and uses the random IV for decryption, thanks.

Comment: The codes are incompatible mainly because the Java code applies AES-256 and the PHP code AES-128, i.e. change the algorithm in the PHP code to AES-256-CBC. The different AES variants produce completely different ciphertexts (in contrast a wrong IV corrupts only the first block / 16 bytes for AES/CBC). Also bear in mind that a string as key and a missing authenticity check with CBC are further vulnerabilities besides a static IV mentioned in the 1st comment.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the solution, based on the suggestion of @Michael Fehr and @Topaco, thanks everyone, and here is the code that worked for me

```
$str = 'Emma';
$key = 'mykey123823196ext470329981320tst';
$iv  = str_repeat(chr(0), 16);
$encodedEncryptedData = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($str, "AES-256-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
echo $encodedEncryptedData; // OUTPUT: wuN9UzYYdmevVxgTxcYIbw==
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).